# Single Sign-on with Duende IdentityServer 4 with use of SAML from (ADFS)

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4, saml-2.0

background:

- have .Net Core 6 app with Core API.
- was able to create Duende Identity Server with use of OIDC

Aim: create SSO with use of IdentityServer and SAML from ADFS

Have no idea where to start, and how to start.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of posts [here](https://authory.com/RoryBraybrook?collection=_all&text=identityserver%20saml%20adfs&type=Article&view=thumbnail&sort=relevance_DESC).

You can use either the Rock Solid Knowledge or Sustainsys SAML stack.

Comment: ok, thanks for that! Will investigate